# How to use PayPal-iOS-SDK?

Tags: ios, paypal, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I want to use the [PayPal-iOS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) in my app, because my customers are heavy users of PayPal for payments. Does iTunes Connect allow it? Please help me find more information!

Comment: Can you rephrase and edit your question?  It's very difficult to tell what your actual question is.

Comment: yeah, i updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your app if you are providing any physical things like in your case you will provide shopping goods then you can implement PayPal for payment, but if you provide any type of service within only app then in that case you have to implement IAP(In App Purchase)